# Modify a flatbuffer to have another convolutional layer

Tags: python, tensorflow-lite, flatbuffers

I should modify a .tflite file to implement convolution 1D op (when I use Conv1D in my model, TF Lite Converter replaces it with Conv2D and expand_dims ops, so I'd like to replace them with my op). Is this possible?
Another problem could be this: even if I could get the modified file, how could I get the binary file to use on a microcontroller?

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible but it's a bit hard to do so.

The simplest option is to use `flatc -t` to convert the tflite file into JSON, once you've modified the JSON file, convert it back to tflite.

https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/flatbuffers_guide_using_schema_compiler.html

Another approach is to use Flatbuffer Python interface. Here are some sample code on how to load and serialize a flatbuffer file programmatically.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/tools/flatbuffer_utils.py

The schema file can be found from here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/schema/schema.fbs

Comment: Thanks for your reply: do you know some examples to use for neural networks?